# Updating row of a table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like this.
[image]

I need to edit this using VBA userform.
I need select a serial no from a list, and other details should be comes to text at the change event.

So I made up the following userform.
[image]

And I added rowSource of serial no list box as serial no. How I should view the toytype, wheel and nale to the text boxes.Appreciate a guidance from you.

Comment: I don't download files from the Internet.

Comment: @Variatus You download files every time you go to a website. Maybe you just don't realize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once no code was provided I'll only do a general explanation.

([Check this link for future questions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/))

First, if you really want to **select** you need to use a ComboBox and before you Load/Show the form use the following code:

```
myArray = ws.Range() 'Define your serial no. range here
With Me.ComboBox
   .List = myArray
End With
```

To update other fields when a value is selected, use a sub like this on the userform:

```
Private Sub myCombo_AfterUpdate()
    'look for Me.myCombo.Value on range and update your textbox
End Sub
```

Comment: I still want to get view the sscific row of a table only based on the combo box value

Comment: Inside the Sub `myCombo_AfterUpdate()` you can do something like `Application.Match(Me.myCombo.Value, ws.Range("A:A"), 0)`